# Mnemotechnic approach to identifying transitive vs verb-adjective constructs

Tags: possessives, transitive-verbs

I'm no linguist, grammarian and not even an english speaker, please bear with me. I'm looking for a quick way to identify transitive vs intransitive constructs, for example, in the sentence

"the plant has buried leaves"

even on google NLP, is incorrectly identified as transitive direct with action, where the plant decided to bury its leaves, just like an ostrich would with its head.

Is there a simple Mnemotechnic way to correctly associate 'bury' as a verb-adjective to 'leaves' or is it a real semantics issue that grammar/syntax can not solve?

Comment: In the meanig you think the sentence has, the verb *has* is transitive and takes *buried leaves* as its direct object. In the other sense of the sentence the verb *buried* is transitive and taked *leaves* as its object. Either way there is a transitive verb taking a direct object.

Comment: What is mnemotechnic?

Comment: I’m a native speaker, and if you’ll excuse the bragging, one with documented strength with English grammar—and I made the same mistake Google did with this sentence on first read. Welcome to the English language: it’s ambiguous.

Comment: Ok, so besides the meaning of it, there's no proper way to make the difference. I suspected it, since the construct sounded like a 'garden sentence', but it's good to know it from Native speakers. thanks all!

Comment: @Mitch mnemotechnic or mnemonics means using a difference sentence using the same construct, but leading to an obvious result. Very useful for latin based languages such as French.

Comment: @Alex [That's not what 'mnemotechnic' means](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/mnemotechnic). Normally it is  considered a variant of mnemonic', something having to do with memory.  Are you thinking of another word? I can't think of any word related to your description: 'different sentence with same construct, but leafing to an obvious result' but that has nothing to do with either memory or with your stated desire for quick identification. If you meant a 'memory aid', don't use 'mnemotechnic', use 'mnemonic' instead. But I think you really want a _rule_ to distinguish pattern.

Comment: Mnenotechnics = the art of memory, in the context of this question, this is exactly what it means (I didn't necessarily want to go into details). This means the mental processes/tricks put into play to remember 'something' (see here https://artofmemory.com/search/node/grammar)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Attempting to analyse sentences in isolation runs counter to what language as a system of communication is. There is no way to disambiguate *the plant has buried leaves* without further context and/or discerning the speaker's intentions. I.e., no you can't tell whether the finite verb is *has buried* or *has* in this sentence.

Comment: The weird thing in all of this, is that if we use 2000 words on a daily basis, how is the brain pulling the right context that fast? It's obvious the plant didn't bury its leaves, but looping on all plausible contexts would take enormous computing power. Whatever, cheers.